# interactively move a point in x and y direction in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, point, interactive

I would like to move a point in x and y direction using sliders. The problem is that as soon as the point has been moved in one direction, it returns to the origin (X0 and Y0 are read again). is it possible to remember the previous x or y position or is there an easier way to do this? thanks for the replies (geogebra is not an option just pyhton)

```
import numpy as np                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

f = lambda y: (1.5*y)
g = lambda x: (1.5*x)
# Start pos
x0 = 0
y0 = 0

# Select length of axes and the space between tick labels
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -5, 5, -5, 5
ticks_frequency = 1

# Plot points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 10))
ptplot, = plt.plot(x0, y0, 'ko')

ax_x = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_y = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

xSlider = Slider(ax_x, 'x', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=x0, valstep=0.1)
ySlider = Slider(ax_y, 'y', -5.0, 5.0, valinit=y0, valstep=0.1)

def update_x(x):
    y = g(x)
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    xSlider.eventson = False
    xSlider.set_val(x)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    xSlider.eventson = True
    print("x1", x)
    print("y1", y)

def update_y(y):
    x = f(y)
    ptplot.set_data(x,y)
    ySlider.eventson = False
    ySlider.set_val(y)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ySlider.eventson = True
    print("x2", x)
    print("y2", y)

xSlider.on_changed(update_x)
ySlider.on_changed(update_y)

# Set identical scales for both axes
ax.set(xlim=(xmin-1, xmax+1), ylim=(ymin-1, ymax+1), aspect='equal')

# Set bottom and left spines as x and y axes of coordinate system
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

# Remove top and right spines
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# Create 'x' and 'y' labels placed at the end of the axes
ax.set_xlabel('x', size=14, labelpad=-24, x=1.03)
ax.set_ylabel('y', size=14, labelpad=-21, y=1.02, rotation=0)

# Create custom major ticks to determine position of tick labels
x_ticks = np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, ticks_frequency)
y_ticks = np.arange(ymin, ymax+1, ticks_frequency)
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks[x_ticks != 0])
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks[y_ticks != 0])

# Create minor ticks placed at each integer to enable drawing of minor grid
# lines: note that this has no effect in this example with ticks_frequency=1
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(ymin, ymax+1), minor=True)

# Draw major and minor grid lines
ax.grid(which='both', color='grey', linewidth=1, linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)

# Draw arrows
arrow_fmt = dict(markersize=4, color='black', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1), (0), marker='>', transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)
ax.plot((0), (1), marker='^', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), **arrow_fmt)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current position of your point with `ptplot.get_data`.
So your update functions could look like this:

```
def update_x(x):
    y = g(x)
    x0, y0 = ptplot.get_data()
    ptplot.set_data(x0 + x, y0 + y)
    xSlider.eventson = False
    xSlider.set_val(x)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    xSlider.eventson = True
    print("x1", x)
    print("y1", y)

def update_y(y):
    x = f(y)
    x0, y0 = ptplot.get_data()
    ptplot.set_data(x0 + x, y0 + y)
    ySlider.eventson = False
    ySlider.set_val(y)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ySlider.eventson = True
    print("x2", x)
    print("y2", y)
```

However, although that is what you asked for, I doubt that this is the logic you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my question was whether I can vary the coordinates of the point P(xly) depending on the controller? So set the x position with the x controller and the y position with the y controller